# Every complete topological vector space is metrizable

Tags: general-topology, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am looking for a proof of the following result:

If $(X,\tau)$ is a complete topological vector space, then $\tau$ is generated by  a complete distance wich is invariant by translations.

My attempt is based on a similar result that I has found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space#Constructing_Fr%C3%A9chet_spaces.
However, why can we ensure the existence of such $\|\cdot\|_k$? and, is it true that $\tau$ is generated by such distance (I don't see any relation between both topologies)?

Comment: How do you define "complete" for a topological space?

Comment: Any Cauchy net is a convergent net

Comment: But what is a Cauchy net if you don't have a metric?

Comment: @RobertIsrael A net $(x_\lambda)$ in a TVS $X$ is Cauchy if for every neighborhood $U$ of $0$, there is some $\lambda_0$ such that whenever $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\geq\lambda_0$, we have $x_{\lambda_1}-x_{\lambda_2}\in U$.

Comment: Yes, @Aweygan. That is the definition of Cauchy net that I am using

Answer (score 1):

Your claimed result is false: $\mathbb{R}^{\omega_1}$ in the product topology is a locally convex complete TVS (in the sense mentioned in the comments) but is *not* metrisable at all.